# Azure pipelines - agent ip changed during single job

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-agent

I have following (simplified) steps in pipeline:

1. Read agent IP;
2. Add agent ip to azure cosmosdb;
3. Run tests which read data from cosmosdb.

Today, for first time for like 1 year + I received error that in step 3 IP from which request to azure comosdb was orignated is different than ip read in step 1. All above steps are under same job (so same agent is used). How it is possible that agent changed it ip during single agent runtime? I think that should be reported to MS but first wanted to know if anyone else thinks/knows otherwise.

Comment: Could you share your pipeline?

Comment: Unfortunately not, but I do not think pipeline setup has anything to do with this

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: @PanWolodyjowsky I have posted same question on ms forum and received information to create a ticket as such behavior is unexpected https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1334376/azure-pipelines-agent-ip-changed-during-single-job. If I will face issue again (it happened twice for like 16 months period) I will do that.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue - 2 tasks: the first whitelists the external IP of the agent, the next task then does a docker push. It works 99/100 but fails randomly as the IP changes between tasks. I will report it